# VirtualizedLists error Flatlist in Scrollview but multiple header component on of them is should be sticky

Tags: typescript, react-native

Hi guys Im trying to clone the Medium UI. This is the homeScreen

- Home Container(should be scroll with flatlist)
- ScrollableTexts (shoul scroll up but stick on the top if scroll to uch)
- Flatlist (normal scroll)

I got VirtualizedLists error I know I shouldn't use flatlist inside the scrollview but I tried section view a little but I dont get it.
Can you guy help me
My code is below

```java
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  Button,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import {Text} from '../../components/atoms/Text/Text';
import {height, width} from '../../utils/hw';
import ArticleCard from '../../components/molecules/articlecard';
import ScrollableTexts from '../../components/molecules/sticky';
import {fetchNewsArticles} from '../../services/news/fetch_news'; // Dizin doğru şekilde güncellenmeli
import {Content, Root} from '../../models/news';
import {ArticleSeparator} from '../../components/atoms/ArticleSeperator/ArticleSeperator';

const HomeScreen: React.FC = () => {
  // const navigation = useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<ParamListBase>>();

  const [newsArticles, setNewsArticles] = useState<Root>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState<Content[]>([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState<number>(1);
  const [isListEnd, setIsListEnd] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const renderFooter = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
        {loading ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" /> : null}
      </View>
    );
  };
  const fetchData = async () => {
    if (!loading && !isListEnd) {
      setLoading(true);
      console.log('fetching data');
      try {
        const articles = await fetchNewsArticles(page, 1);
        if (articles.content.length > 0) {
          setPage(page + 1);
          setDataSource([...dataSource, ...articles.content]);
          setLoading(false);
        } else {
          setIsListEnd(true);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching news articles:', error);
      }
    }
  };
  const HomeContainer = () => {
    return (<View style={styles.headerContainer}>
      <Text fontFam="bold" style={styles.header}>
        Home
      </Text>
    </View>);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1}}>
      {/* <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      /> */}
      <ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}>
        <HomeContainer/>
        <ScrollableTexts />
        {/* <View>
          {newsArticles?.content.map(article => {
            return <ArticleCard article={article} key={article.newsUUID} />;
          })}
        </View> */}
        <FlatList
          data={dataSource}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <ArticleSeparator />}
          renderItem={({item}) => <ArticleCard article={item} />}
          ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
          onEndReached={fetchData}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
  },
  headerContainer: {
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    height: height * 0.15,
  },
  header: {
    paddingLeft: 20,
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  stickyHeaderContainer: {
    height: height * 0.05,
    width: width,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  footerContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
});

export default HomeScreen;
```